# How to allow the user to place a point as input for a geoprocessing model?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is there an analogue to Esri's "Feature Set" in QGIS modeller.  I am interested in creating a model that allows the user to place a point feature on a map as an input variable for a geoprocessing model.  I've done this in ModelBuilder, but want to replicate the effort in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do this currently is to instruct the user to create a point layer (with one point) which is then used as vector layer input in the Processing model.

As far as I know, the Processing scripts and models currently don't provide any user interaction capabilities.

If you need user interactions, you can write a plugin instead. The plugin would take care of the interaction handling and can call Processing functions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In modern QGIS you can use the `Point Input` in combination with `Create Layer from Point` algorithm to achieve this. See also [How to actually use the Point Input for other algorithms](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428341/how-to-actually-use-the-point-input-for-other-algorithms/428342#428342).