# Using Point input for other algorithm in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-modeler, input

I added a Model Input "`Point Input`" to my model. If I now launch the model from the Processing toolbox the user can click the <kbd>...</kbd> icon and click on a point on the map.

How can I use the result of that in my model then? I tried making a buffer around it but the Buffer algorithm does not let me select the `Point Input` as `Input layer`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ["Create Layer from Point"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#create-layer-from-point) algorithm to create a usable model "object" from that clicked point:

[image]

It's documentation (accessible if you open it in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)) states:

> This algorithm creates a new vector layer that contains a single
> feature with geometry matching a point parameter.
>
> It can be used in models to convert a point into a layer which can
> be used for other algorithms which require a layer based input.